# Continuous Time out protractor

Tags: selenium, angularjs, selenium-chromedriver, protractor

I am trying to use protractor for testing e2e app with angular but getting timeout. I have started selenium server and chrome driver also.

Comment: resolved the issue by increasing the time of test suite.

Comment: I'm getting the same timeout problem... it navigates to my home page and then just waits for forever until I get `Error: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds` and it times out.  I tried increasing the timeout in the config to: `defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000` but that didn't help.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the angular code you are testing against doesn't use $timeout... make it use $interval

Answer (score 0):

I am having timeout problems too and I think the reason is that my app is using $timeout and not using $interval. Found an answer to this in GitHub. Please have a look at the end of the issue ["Protractor E2E test times out when app polls an API at regular intervals"](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/49) it is stated that "With Angular 1.2rc3, you can now use the $interval service to do your polling!" along with [this link to further details.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/2b5ce84fca7b41fca24707e163ec6af84bc12e83)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's solved by now. Else could have a look at https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md which states that Time Outs can be various reasons and also proposes the solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but i did have the problem at the beginning too and i hope that you already solved the issue.

But if not, you need to tell Protractor not to wait for Angular $http and $timeout, like this way:

**Old deprecated way:**

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

**New correct way:**

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```